# Como ordenar campo do tipo VARCHAR em CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Como ordenar campos do tipo `VARCHAR` na classe `model` do CodeIgniter?

Já conseguir no SQL puro dessa forma:

```
order by strtodate(dtdespesa, '%d-%m-%Y') desc;
```

Contudo a versão do CodeIgniter que estou utilizando, a 3.1.6, não reconhece essa função: `strtodate`.

```
$this->db->order_by (strtodate('dtandamento', '%d/%m/%Y'));
```

- Versão do CI: 3.1.6
- Versão do PHP 5.3.7

Comment: Coloca o código do codeigniter formando a query com a função

Comment: $this->db->order_by (strtodate('dtandamento', '%d/%m/%Y'));

Comment: a função está funcionando certinha, o que está pegando é o order_by

Comment: já tentou: `$this->db->order_by("strtodate('dtandamento', '%d/%m/%Y')", 'ASC', FALSE);`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, acabei de tentar. Deu a mesma mensagem:

Message: Call to undefined function strtodate()

Comment: coloque todo o código!

Comment: Funcionou!!! Só acrescentei o nome da outra tabela e ordenou do jeito que eu queria. Muito obrigado @VirgilioNovic

$this->db->order_by ("str_to_date(andamento.dtandamento, '%d-%m-%Y')", 'DESC', FALSE);

Comment: Ramiro coloquei como resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No último parâmetro do método [order_by](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results) coloque `FALSE`, para que o texto digitado seja incluído sem alteração no que foi escrito, ou seja, os dados não serão escapado, exemplo:

```
$this->db->order_by("strtodate('dtandamento', '%d/%m/%Y')", 'ASC', FALSE);
```

no seu caso em especifico:

```
$this->db->order_by ("str_to_date(andamento.dtandamento, '%d-%m-%Y')", 'DESC', FALSE);
```